# Custom row action on custom posts list page causes a wp_die?

Tags: hacks, row-actions

The scenario is this:

I have a CPT called Job. I've set custom row actions for this CPT, and most of them are linked to external or custom settings pages. They work fine.

Now I've set a new row action, called as 'mark-special', and I've set the href for the link as the same posts list page with my own params as:

`edit.php?post_type=job&action=mark-special&job_id=123&_wpnonce=<custom nonce>`

I'm handling the action in a function hooked with `init`.

The problem is, when I click this link, it `wp_die`s with a message: `Are you sure you want to do this?`. But the function works as I want it to, and the CPT is set as special.

Any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I have used `action` as a url arg, which WP uses for all its actions such as `approve_comment`, `trash_post` etc. Changed it to a custom word and my code worked like a charm!